# Can I connect a printer that only has a RJ11 socket to my router's RJ45 ethernet cable?

Tags: ethernet, printer, network-printer

I have an HP OfficeJet J4500 all-in-one printer, currently connected via USB to a computer, but I'd like to connect it directly to the router's ethernet instead in order to print from other computers on the network.

The printer only has a RJ11 ("fax") socket. I know there are RJ11 to RJ45 adapters. 
Can I use one to connect the printer to my router?

Comment: RJ11 is a phone jack, not a networking Jack. Best guess without the manual is it was for a fax line.

Comment: @Tetsujin Yes, it says "fax" on the printer – so no chance to connect it via ethernet?

Comment: Very much doubt it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An RJ11 is a telephone connector. When used in a printer this is usually for faxing.

In either case, this is an analog connector which works very differently than an RJ45 connector. RJ11 has only 2 wires inside the cable, one for data/audio and the other for ring. An RJ45 connector has 8 wires inside the cable of which 4 are used for sure (higher speeds require the other 4 wires).

This is a digital cable however and works very differently. As such it is not possible in any way to use the fax port as a network port.